# Is there a way to write class inside function in drools as we had in drools 2.x?

Tags: xml, java-8, drools

In our application we are using drools 2.x XML rules, when we moved to jdk 8 we had "error constructing import" exception since we have used import statements inside `<java:functions><![CDATA[  ]]><java:functions>`.
Its a product with around 140+ rules. Looking for a way to fix it.
if not we need to move to latest versions of drools, probably 4.x or 5.x.

Any clue here will help
**OR**
Can we write whole class within function in new .drl or .xml files as we do in drools 2.x?

**ERROR:**

```
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; error constructing import
    at org.drools.io.FunctionsHandler.end(FunctionsHandler.java:112)
    at org.drools.io.RuleSetReader.endElement(RuleSetReader.java:618)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
    at org.drools.io.RuleSetReader.read(RuleSetReader.java:445)
    at org.drools.io.RuleSetReader.read(RuleSetReader.java:325)
    at org.drools.io.RuleBaseLoader.loadFromReader(RuleBaseLoader.java:313)
    at org.drools.io.RuleBaseLoader.loadFromReader(RuleBaseLoader.java:271)
    at org.drools.io.RuleBaseLoader.loadFromReader(RuleBaseLoader.java:256)
```

Below is how my XML looks

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rule-set name="WorkingRuleSet" xmlns="http://drools.org/rules" xmlns:java="http://drools.org/semantics/java">
<application-data identifier="enabled">java.util.HashMap</application-data>
<application-data identifier="audit">com.business.service.AuditService</application-data>
<java:functions><![CDATA[
    public static class MappingHelper {
        public static method1(){
        ..........
        }
    }
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
    public static class LoggerUtil{
        public static method1(){
        ..........
        }
    }
]]></java:functions>
<rule name="Ping adapter_0" xmlns:java="http://drools.org/semantics/java">
   <parameter identifier="action">
     <java:class>com.business.action.Action</java:class>
   </parameter>
   <java:condition>action != null</java:condition>
   <java:condition>action.getName().equals(constant.ACTION_PING_ADAPTER)</java:condition>
   <java:consequence>
        import com.business.ejb.rules.RulesHelper;
        RulesHelper.getPlatformAPI().getDispatcher(ctx).ping(); 
   </java:consequence>
 <java:condition>enabled.get("Ping adapter_0") != null</java:condition></rule>
 <rule name="Ping adapter_1" xmlns:java="http://drools.org/semantics/java">
   <parameter identifier="action">
     <java:class>com.business.action.Action</java:class>
   </parameter>

   <java:condition>action != null</java:condition>
   <java:condition>action.getName().equals(constant.ACTION_PING_ADAPTER)</java:condition>

   <java:consequence>
        import com.business.ejb.rules.RulesHelper;
        RulesHelper.getPlatformAPI().getDispatcher(ctx).ping();
   </java:consequence>
 <java:condition>enabled.get("Ping adapter_1") != null</java:condition></rule>
 </rule-set>
```

On execution of below method am getting the error.
This happens on call of below method.

**'org.drools.io.RuleBaseLoader.loadFromReader(new StringReader(finalResult.toString()));'**

we are passing xml in form of buffer.

Comment: The latest version of Drools is 7. Drools 5 is over 10 years old.

Comment: Thanks @Roddy. Is there any way to write whole class inside function and then use it in "then part" as we had in old xml rules?

Comment: This is the error which am getting exactly when running with java7. It is a product with 140+ rules. so i am looking for any way to fix this. If not i have to move to latest version.

Comment: Honestly 140 isn't so many ... I support 1.5 million. ;) That being said, what is the actual parsing issue with the import?

Comment: This is how my xml looks

Comment: This happens on call of below method.
'org.drools.io.RuleBaseLoader.loadFromReader(new StringReader(finalResult.toString()));'
we are passing xml in form of buffer.